# SQL Return every row even if Null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, self-join

I want to return all rows from a Contracts table but a second WHERE clause yields only rows which are not null.  (In other words in the code below the 'CAD' restriction means approx half the possible rows have no value traded in Canadian Dollars and thus are not returned --whereas I want all possible rows returned showing NULL values where applicable).

I figure it's a Left Self Join but am struggling with the syntax (and/or whether I need to do an Inner Select),

```
 SELECT MeasurableID,
     EntityID,
     MIN (ContractPrice) AS LowPrice,
     MAX (ContractPrice) AS HighPrice

 FROM dbo.Contracts

 WHERE dbo.Contracts.MeasurableID = 2018
  AND  Contracts.CurrencyCode IN ( 'CAD' ) 

 GROUP BY
  dbo.Contracts.MeasurableID,
  dbo.Contracts.EntityID
```

Comment: `WHERE dbo.Contracts.MeasurableID = 2018 AND  (Contracts.CurrencyCode IN ( 'CAD' )  OR Contracts.CurrencyCode IS NULL)`

Comment: add or with 'null' in where clause, as of now it checks only IN ('CAD')

Comment: Contracts.CurrencyCode is never NULL (i.e. other contracts are in USD or INR etc) so this does not help.

Comment: Please edit clarifications into your question, not comments. Also if you have another question, post it as a question, not in a comment. Also, you are really not clearly explaining what you want, please edit to be clear. (Eg is your first sentence's "but" a refinement on the spec or a problem with the query?) Also this is not a self-join or a left join, it doesn't have join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT  
  MeasurableID,
  EntityID,
  MIN (CASE WHEN CurrencyCode = 'CAD' THEN ContractPrice END) AS LowPrice,
  MAX (CASE WHEN CurrencyCode = 'CAD' THEN ContractPrice END) AS HighPrice
FROM dbo.Contracts
WHERE MeasurableID = 2018
GROUP BY MeasurableID, EntityID
ORDER BY MeasurableID, EntityID;
```

Comment: Awesome, this works great to solve issue as posted.  I need to read up on Conditional Aggregation though since actual situation has three additional WHERE clauses.

Comment: There isn't much to read up. With `CASE WHEN` I decide when to consider the ContractPrice. You can add an `ELSE NULL` if you find that more readable. `MIN` and `MAX` ignore nulls. That's all.

Comment: Yep, but even before that I actually want to pass to the query above a set of CurrencyCodes in a UserDefinedTable.  However the following is throwing the error "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery." 

MIN (CASE WHEN dbo.Contracts.CurrencyCode IN ( SELECT CurrencyCode from @TempTable4params ) THEN ContractPrice END) AS LowPrice,

Comment: Ah, one of those annoying restrictions in SQL Server. Then do this in two steps: 1) Write the query without aggregation. 2) Write a main query where you select from this query and aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, Thorsten answered the question as posted but per comments below his answer it could not be put into practice.  Thus instead I have had to code it this way:

```
    SELECT
        t1.MeasurableID,
        t1.EntityID,
        t2.HIGH,
        t2.LOW
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                MeasurableID,
                EntityID
            FROM
                Contracts
            WHERE
                MeasurableID IN (2017, 2018)
            GROUP BY
                MeasurableID,
                EntityID
        ) t1
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            MeasurableID,
            EntityID,
            MAX (ContractPrice) AS HIGH,
            MIN (ContractPrice) AS LOW
        FROM
            Contracts
        WHERE
            MeasurableID IN (2017, 2018)
        AND CurrencyCode IN ('CAD', 'BTC')
        GROUP BY
            MeasurableID,
            EntityID
    ) t2 ON t1.MeasurableID = t2.MeasurableID
    AND t1.EntityID = t2.EntityID
    ORDER BY
        t1.MeasurableID,
        t1.EntityID;
```

Answer (score 0):

used group by..

select * from Adjusters group by CompanyID;