# SQL get row values for MAX() grouped by 2 columns

Tags: sql-server, group-by, max

Following on from [SQL Return every row even if Null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46497384/sql-return-every-row-even-if-null-values/46505027#46505027)  I need to SELECT the row data associated with the MAX(contractPrice) when grouped by two columns.

I've set up sqlfiddle.com/#!6/170043/2 to demonstrate that the problem is the code below returns duplicates (see 5th and 6th lines of sqlfiddle results) if the max price is repeated.

```
    SELECT
        t1.MeasurableID,
        t1.EntityID,
        t1.ContractPrice,
        ID,
        UTCMatched,
        NumberOfContracts,
        CurrencyCode
    FROM
        contracts AS t1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            MeasurableID,
            EntityID,
            MAX (contractprice) AS MAXprice
        FROM
            contracts
        WHERE
            MeasurableID IN (2017, 2018)
        AND CurrencyCode IN ('CAD', 'BTC')
        GROUP BY
            MeasurableID,
            EntityID
    ) t2 ON t1.MeasurableID = t2.MeasurableID
    AND t1.EntityID = t2.EntityID
    AND t1.ContractPrice = t2.MAXprice
    WHERE
        t1.MeasurableID IN (2017, 2018)
    AND t1.CurrencyCode IN ('CAD', 'BTC')
    ORDER BY
        MeasurableID,
        EntityID,
        UTCMatched
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that are very confusing or need clarification here:

1. Your tag is `Sql-Server`, but you provided us with a sample with `MySql`
2. The usage of a derived table doesn't seem necessary, in fact it makes it a bit confusing.

With that said, if you want the MAX `ContractPrice` with its MAX `ID` this can be accomplished several ways. Also please note I did not aggregate the rest of the columns properly, which is bad practice. Just wrap the rest of the columns that have not been aggregated or grouped in a MAX():

```
SELECT 
    t1.MeasurableID,
    t1.EntityID,
    MAX(t1.contractprice) AS MAXprice,
    MAX(t2.ID) as ID,
    MAX(t2.UTCMatched) as UTCMatched,
    MAX(t2.NumberOfContracts) AS NumberOfContracts,
    MAX(t2.CurrencyCode) AS CurrencyCode

FROM
    contracts t1
LEFT JOIN contracts t2 ON t1.MeasurableID = t2.MeasurableID
                          AND
                          t1.EntityID = t2.EntityID
                          AND
                          t1.ContractPrice = t2.ContractPrice

WHERE
    t1.MeasurableID IN (2017, 2018)
AND t1.CurrencyCode IN ('CAD', 'BTC')
GROUP BY
    t1.MeasurableID,
    t1.EntityID
```

The other method is, if this is actually SQL-Server, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` and a derived table:

```
SELECT MeasurableID
       ,EntityID
       ,ContractPrice
       ,ID
       ,UTCMatched
       ,NumberOfContracts
       ,CurrencyCode
FROM
(SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EntityID ORDER BY ContractPrice, ID DESC ) rn
FROM Contracts t1) t1
WHERE t1.rn = 1
```

Comment: 1.)  Sorry my error on sqlfiddle here is link for SQL-Server  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/170043/2

2.)  I will try your code and advise, thanks.

Comment: Note that your first code block throws the error:  "Column 'contracts.UTCmatched' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."  and that even if the latter three selects are removed the MAX(ID) that is returned is the highest ID value (rather than the ID value associated with the highest price).

Comment: Yes, I've noted the columns need to be aggregated properly. I've updated it to reflect what I mean. Go ahead and run it again.

Comment: @MikeS I see what you mean now, in that case you'll want the second query.

Comment: @MikeS If I understand you correctly, if the ContractPrice and EntityID is the same, you want the greater ID? I've updated the second query.

Comment: Yes you are basically correct the higher ID would in my architecture be the more recent in time and thus the desired ID to display.  I'll post the actual code below but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your query can by simplifed and "corrected" :

```
   SELECT
        t1.MeasurableID,
        t1.EntityID,
        t1.ContractPrice,
        t1.ID,
        t1.UTCMatched,
        t1.NumberOfContracts,
        t1.CurrencyCode
    FROM contracts AS t1
    INNER JOIN contracts AS T2 ON (t1.MeasurableID = t2.MeasurableID AND MeasurableID IN (2017, 2018) AND CurrencyCode IN ('CAD', 'BTC'))
    ORDER BY
        t1.MeasurableID,
        t1.EntityID,
        t1.ContractPrice,
        t1.ID,
        t1.UTCMatched,
        t1.NumberOfContracts,
        t1.CurrencyCode
    HAVING t1.ContractPrice = MAX(T2.contractprice)
```

But I thing you will still have duplicates... I think your whole query concept is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

P.S. I can eliminate duplicates by using Row_Number() -- per code below:

```
        SELECT MeasurableID
             ,EntityID
             ,ContractPrice
             ,ID AS HighTradeID
             ,UTCMatched AS HighTradeUTC
             ,NumberOfContracts AS HighTradeNumberOfContracts
             ,CurrencyCode AS HighTradeCurrency
FROM
        (SELECT *
                        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MeasurableID, EntityID ORDER BY ContractPrice DESC, ID DESC ) RowNumber
        FROM Contracts t1
            WHERE
                MeasurableID IN (2017, 2018)
            AND CurrencyCode IN ('CAD', 'BTC')
        ) AS InnerSelect

WHERE InnerSelect.RowNumber = 1
```